# Tweaking mysql for upload large feed

Tags: vps, whm

I am uploading feed of products on my wordpress its very slow in importing. 
i just need help to tweak my mysql to improve uploading of feed currently i am using centos 8gb ram 8cpus..  I want to improve my.cnf can someone make good my.cnf to improve feed uploading thanks

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
performance-schema=on
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 512M
# sort_buffer_size = 1024K
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 1024K
datadir=/var/lib/mysql`enter code here`
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

performance-schema=on
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

performance-schema=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
```

Comment: I would advise to post your import script, unless you're using mysql console client to import the data from an .sql file. There may be lots to improve in the script before checking your mysql config

Answer (score 0):

[image: Import Settings]

i am using shopify theme for woocommerce. using wp all import plugin to upload feed